# Can I change a jQuery code with an input value?

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have this jQuery code:

```
$.get('blog.html', function(data){ 
    $(data).find(".post img").appendTo(".post-thumbnail");
});
```

And I have this HTML input box:

```
<input type='text' name="domain" id="url" />
```

Is it possible to take the value of the input box and have it replace the '.blog.html' in the jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the value, and make the request with the value in the input box. The 'url' variable will contain the current value of the input element with the name 'domain'.

```
var url = $("input[name=domain]").val();
$.get(url, function(data){ 
    $(data).find(".post img").appendTo(".post-thumbnail");
});
```

Comment: Ah, it was the ".val()" that made all of the difference. Thanks, Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

- listen for the input's `"input"` event!
- get `url` using `$.trim(this.value) + '.html'` (trimming occasional wrapping whitespaces)

```
function getPage() { 

  var url = $.trim(this.value) + ".html";

  $.get( url, function (data) { 
      $(data).find(".post img").appendTo(".post-thumbnail");
  });

}


$("#url").on("input", getPage);
```